# Hibernate: adding a new column in joined table

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

there are 3 tables `Order` table `Product` table `OrderProductMapping` table
there are only 2 entity clases : `Order` and `Product`
`Order` and `Product` tables share a `many-tomany` relationship. Which means 1 order can have many products and one product can belong to many orders.
And to map this, there is the third table named `OrderProductMapping`

Below is my the mapping from `order.hbm` file

```
<set name="product" table="OrderProductMapping">
    <key column="orderId"/>
    <many-to-many class="Product">
        <column name="productId" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

Below is the mapping from `product.hbm` file

```
<set name="order" table="OrderProductMapping" inverse="true">
    <key>
        <column name="orderId"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many class="Product">
        <column name="productId" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

Now I need to introduce a new column in mapping table how should proceed? any help or pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Entity OrderProductMapping and then replace the @ManytoMany with bidirectional @OneToMany Order > OrderProductMapping < Product.

See also:

[Hibernate Best Practices: Avoiding Many-To-Many and 'exotic' relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594234/hibernate-best-practices-avoiding-many-to-many-and-exotic-relationships)