# JPA Many to many association entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm

I am developing Java EE project with embedded database using JPA ORM. My question is...

When I create @ManyToMany fields in two Entities, I have to create association entity too, or it will do container for me?

Course entity snippet

```
        Public class Course implements Serializable {
    ...
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

            @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name="course_user", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
        private List<User> enrolledStudents;
    ...
```

User Entity snippet

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="enrolledStudents")
    private List<Course> enrolledCourses;
...
```

So is this everything I need or not? Thank you for answers!

Comment: My (not so) old memory of JPA says yes, this is everything you need, but not sure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work but see here:

[Hibernate Best Practices: Avoiding Many-To-Many and 'exotic' relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594234/hibernate-best-practices-avoiding-many-to-many-and-exotic-relationships)

At some point you will most likely want to save additional info about this relationship (enrollment date for example?) So you may as well create the 'join entity' up front to save refactoring later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its all you need... if you create the database from the code, you will see three tables... Course, User and Course_User witch has the IDs of Couse and User

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is sufficient. Look at examples at 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany