# Is it possible to create a surrogate primary key in the many-to-many join table in hibernate/JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create Entities to map to tables that already exist in the database.

Comment: In this scenario you map an entity to the Join Table and then map the two associated entities to this using `@OneToMany`.

Comment: @Alan Hay Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of using an ORM framework? Having database table specific classes in the object oriented side?

Comment: The Hibernate Docs actually recommend to avoid using `@ManyToMany` and actually suggest you should, in most cases, use a Join entity. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594234/hibernate-best-practices-avoiding-many-to-many-and-exotic-relationships

Comment: @Alan Hay Interesting and informative read. Thanks for sharing.