# JPA @ManytoMany with extra data in "join table"

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, join

I'm trying to join 2 entities(Customer and Address) by using a join table. In one Entity i have the following:

```
 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(
 name = "CustomerAddress",
 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerID", referencedColumnName = "CustomerID"),
 inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AddressID", referencedColumnName = "AddressID"))
 private List<Address> address;
```

In the join table there is a field called type(a string/varchar) that can't be null. Fetching addresses from customer works fine but when i try to add addresses to a customer-object and then commiting a query, i get the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AddressType', table
>   'LiaFlexData.SalesLT.CustomerAddress'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.

Comment: please tell us WHAT Java object this "type" column maps on to? Because if it doesnt map on to a Java object then don't expect JPA to "know about it"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Best Practices: Avoiding Many-To-Many and 'exotic' relationships](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594234/hibernate-best-practices-avoiding-many-to-many-and-exotic-relationships)

Comment: type is a String/varchar

Comment: And? I asked WHAT Java object it maps to. In your CLASSES.

Comment: None. It is in the join table(that joins the 2 other tables).