# Extra columns in many-to-many Spring Data JPA Relationship with minimal changes

Tags: java, jpa

I need to make a change in the project's model. Nowadays we have two classes with bidirectional many-to-many relationship (which implies in an relationship table) and need now to add extra informations to the relationship.

My question is: The only way to do it is create a class for the relationship (e.g. creating this one with the same name of the relationship table that already exists)?

I'm asking it because if we need to change the above relationship in the project, the change will be very impacting, almost the whole project (seriously).

The two classes that I'm talking about, just to make it clearer:

```
@Entity
public class Serie extends AbstractEntity {
   @ManyToMany
   private List<Disciplina> disciplinas;
}

@Entity
public class Disciplina extends AbstractEntity {
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "disciplinas")
   private List<Serie> series;
}
```

Comment: Why?  You don't need to expose the implementation. You can still return `List<Disciplina>` and   `List<Serie>` by processing the in-memory model and not exposing the relationships to the Join entity.

Comment: What you have in mind is to add a column in the serie_disciplina table and access it through the model? If so there are various way such as the introduction of Map in the model.

Comment: @garfield, the table already exists (the hibernate makes it by default when we made the relationship for the first time). What I need is to add more information to the relationship.

Comment: @AlanHay, how can I access the new information using the relationship as it is for now? I need to put more information on the serie_disciplinas table and use it in code. But making a new class to do it (SerieDisciplinas e.g.) there will be needed a lot of changes in code and in the query's. My question concern about if there is another way to do it without so much changes.

Comment: I forget to say that the query's are made in HQL, what implies that are made using the java model, not the tables.

Comment: @Filipe Mendes it would be useful to know what extra information is included in the join table. One solution is to keep your original entities and map the join table to a new entity, with ManyToOne Relationships to the original entities, then replace the ManyToMany to the original entities to OneToMany to the entity mapping the join table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As advised in the comments you need a join entity but do not need to expose this to clients of your domain model: by doing something like the below you would only need to change any client code that directly modifies the collections to call the addXXX/removeXXX methods. No client code is only aware of Join entity. So changes to your Java code should be minor.

As for queries well you will obviously need to change these as required.

Serie

```
@Entity
public class Serie extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "serie")
    private List<SerieDisciplina> serieDisciplinas;

    public List<Disciplina> getDisciplinas(){
            //disciplinas extracted from serieDisciplinas 
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(...); 
    }

    public void addDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina){
        SerieDisciplina sd = new SerieDisciplina();
        sd.stSerie(this);
        sd.setDisciplina(disciplina);

        serieDesciplinas.add(sd);   
    }
}
```

Disciplina

```
@Entity
public class Disciplina extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "disciplina")
    private List<SerieDisciplina> serieDisciplinas;

    public List<Serie> getSeries(){
        //series extracted from serieDisciplinas
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(...); 
    }

    public void addSerie(Serie serie){
        SerieDisciplina sd = new SerieDisciplina();
        sd.stSerie(Serie);
        sd.setDisciplina(this);

        serieDesciplinas.add(sd);
    }
}
```

Join Entity

```
@Entity 
public class SerieDisciplina{
    @ManyToOne
    private Serie serie;

    @ManyToOne
    private Disciplina disciplina;

    //fields for the additional data about the relationship

    //getters and setters
}
```

The Hibernate docs suggest avoiding `@ManyToMany` in the first place to avoid such problems. See discussion at: [Hibernate Best Practices: Avoiding Many-To-Many and 'exotic' relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18594234/1356423)