# JPA Many-to-Many mapping

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I have this model(model-1) where I´m using JPA to manage the data.
It´s working just fine.
[image]

Now I need to add one more column on user_account_group called account_id.
[image]

Now, I´m not able to save a new user_account due to the extra column. What is the best approach to fix this issue?

```
public class UserAccount{
  @ManyToMany
@JoinTable
(
    name="user_account_user_group",
    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="user_account_id", referencedColumnName="id") },
    inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="user_group_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true) }
)
private List<UserGroup> userGroups;
}

public class UserGroup
{
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="userGroups")  
private List<UserAccount> accounts;
}

public class Account
{  //no mapping }
```

Comment: You need to create a new 'Join' entity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222777/extra-columns-in-many-to-many-spring-data-jpa-relationship-with-minimal-changes/50248727#50248727

Comment: @AlanHay, can you be more specific? What kind of join do I need? Jointable or Joincolumn? I´m dont have much experience with JPA.