# How to Map two entities of the same type in JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have a case where I need to create a compatibility mapping between computer hardware parts.

The idea is to check for example if ComputerPart1(motherboard_yy) is compatible with ComputerPart1(hardrive_xx)

So I have an Entity called ComputerPart

```
@Entity
public class ComputerPart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String serialNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String manufacturer;

    // getter and setters
```

I'm not sure about the best way to do next.

Do I create an object map of computerParts with a List?

```
Map<ComputerPart, List<ComputerPart>>
```

Or Do I create another Entity Called Compatible?

The solution that I will probably chose is having a list of the same Entity Type:

```
@Entity
    public class ComputerPart {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String serialNumber;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String manufacturer;


        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String manufacturer;

       // What @Annotation to put here?
       //is it @ManyToMany ? 
       Set<ComputerPart> compatibles;
```

I'm not sure about the Annotation parameters.

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = ComputerPart.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "??", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "??", referencedColumnName = "??")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "??", referencedColumnName = "??")})
```

Comment: You can use `@ManyToMany` as you have proposed. Join table and columns can be whatever you want. You could also, as you have alluded to (and this is the recommended solution), create a 3rd entity Compatability and map that using `@OneToMany`. On avoiding `@ManyToMany` see further: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18594234/1356423

Comment: hey Alan, thanks for replying. Good to know that the many-to-many isn't preferred. So basically each Entity (ComputerPart and ComputerPartCompatible) would have each a @OneToMany to the other Entity?